# HTML5 SVG File embedding

Tags: html, svg, coffeescript

On my site I embed a few SVG files, and the file they display is changed by JavaScript (CoffeeScript). I use an `<object>` tag to embed the file.

The code to change the file looks like this:

```
element.querySelector("object").data = "assets/images/#{icon}"
```

This all works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox and Safari, sometimes the SVG files don't display, while the `data` attribute of the object is set.

If I use the `setAttribute` method, it takes a while for the images to show up.

```
element.querySelector("object").setAttribute "data", "assets/images/#{icon}"
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds a bit like something that's fixed in Firefox 35. Try a nightly and see if it's fixed there.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a solution that works in any recent browser, as it's my personal website

Comment: The fix I'm thinking of has just been migrated to Firefox 34.